# SQL query to Python , Using Pandas

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, text-mining

I have a SQL table TweetData, it has a Column Tweets, so to mine few keywords from Tweets I'm currently using SQL query as

```
SELECT Tweets, 'Camera Quality'  as CameraQuality
FROM TweetData
WHERE Tweets like '%camera%'
AND Tweets like '%amazing%'
```

my question is, is it possible to do the same thing in python using pandas?

Comment: http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/

Comment: I'm searching for pandas equivalent

Comment: Then search for it... http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.2/cookbook/Chapter%209%20-%20Loading%20data%20from%20SQL%20databases.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need first to load your data into a collection holder object like dataframe. Then you are able to use code like this:

```
df[['Tweets', 'Camera Quality']][(df['Tweets'].str.contains("camera")) & (df['Tweets'].str.contains("amazing"))]
```

this returns what you need.